# Simple f-string claiming to be invalid syntax when it was copied and pasted

Tags: python, python-3.x, printing, console, f-string

I am on day two of starting to learn Python and already got stuck on what will be a really simple problem. I am trying to do an f-string to type out my name but for some reason, it's saying my syntax is invalid. I typed it in exactly how it is in Matthes' book on page 21 and it's still saying my syntax is wrong.

Here is what I have:

```
first_name = "adrian"
last_name = "lastname"
# having trouble on line 23
full_name = f"{first_name} {last_name}"
print(full_name.title())
```

Does anyone see something I am not?

Here's a screenshot of the error message:

[image: screenshot showing error message]

Comment: Never post images of code please.

Comment: Hi! When asking questions here, always try to post some code to help us out (using the code formatter). Additionally, I totally recommend using https://realpython.com to learn some of these basics. Here is a good link to a page about fstrings: https://realpython.com/python-f-strings/

Comment: f-strings weren't added until Python 3.6, so perhaps you're using an earlier version of the interpreter (I can't tell from the screenshot).

Comment: @martineau The image (now removed) showed python 3.8

Comment: How do I make sure I am running 3.8 on my computer. When I go into my command prompt it says something like 2.6 unless I specifically type in python3 then it says 3.8. How would I know my IDE is using 3.8?

Comment: @PedroLobito: The screenshot says the **framework** is 3.8, not the interpreter that's running.

Comment: @adrian91142: `print(sys.version_info)` (after `import sys`) to see what's running.

Comment: sys.version_info(major=2, minor=7, micro=16, releaselevel='final', serial=0)

Comment: The interpreter is the program that's running your Python code — and you're using version 2.7.16,  not 3.6+

Comment: {
 "cmd" : ["python3", "-u", "$file"]
} .          This is what I have on there

Comment: Sorry, but that means nothing to me since I don't know what it is nor even what "framework" (or IDE) you're using. Something isn't configured or installed properly. Also when referencing a book, please mention its title (not just its author).